# Stuck at Removing Conflicting Operating System Files 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

I know this is a known bug and there are other posts about it such as [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613660/stuck-on-removing-conflicting-operating-system-files-while-upgrading-from-14-0?noredirect=1)
However the posts don't do me any good or skip a step or a hundred. First, they say to "Continue with the installation". Huh I am stuck at:

[image]

I do not see a continue button??

I assume I need to hard reset the machine as nothing else is working, but these are important details missing in all workarounds I have found.

Some background:
I have not used this machine for a while, I booted it up it was fine, but said that TeamViewer need to be updated (12). I tried the automatic update which did nothing so I found it online and tried installing. The progress bar froze for a few hours so I tried restarting. The restart also got hung after closing everything to I reset the machine. At boot I got nothing but a purple screen and recovery mode got stuck with a kernel panic. I attempted a boot repair which did not work. Then I tried booting from a 14.04.5 disk to try to reinstall. There was no re-install options. only in parallel or erase, or other. But here I got the "No Root File System Defined", which is easy to look up and says all I need to do is set a partition to / Root, but no instructions on how to do it.
I tried a 16.04.6 boot disk which gave me an update option so it could continue. This was hours ago and the picture shows what I have.

If I reboot, do I continue with the install, do an update or Other and what do I do.
All the guides list some console commands, but I don't have a console, just the update gui.

Sorry if am a pain, but I have been doing this for about 6 hours and am no closer to getting it working.

Thank you.

**Update:**
So I did reboot it and tried the install again. This time even 16.04 no longer gave an update or even parallel install only erase or Something Else:[image: Something Else]

Then you get the partition list.
[image: Partition List]
Now as far picking the partitions, I eventually figured out that double clicking on a line gives details about that partition.
I double clicked the ext4 partition and selected Ext4 from the drop down menu and make sure to NOT select format. At the bottom of the window for mounting select / for root. The efi and swap where correctly identified and could not be changed.

I did install, entered the same username and password as before and the install completed and returned me to the desktop with my files and folder, but none of my old applications.

I did try the rest of the workaround, but mounting the partitions to see what is in them did not work, even with sudo. There are no errors, but I do not see any actual browsable mounts to look into.

Is there a way to get all my programs back or do I now need to spend the weekend reinstalling everything again?

Thanks again.

**Update 2**
I tried mounting the partitions, but could not find anything in them beyond the root. I don't think I have a separate /home partitions. I did check another functional Ubuntu install which also did not have a partition.

I started installing all my programs and packages. Most importantly R and Rstudio and dependencies.
At some point I had some errors due to missing dependencies and an error such as Install is not possible.

Searching online I found a post suggesting `aptitude` which is better for handling errors.
In aptitude when I first tried the install it said there where missing packages and offered to install them. I chose Y but the install failed.
The second time I chose n, then it gave a very long list of packages it could downgrade, I said Y and after it finished the packages installed without issue.

Interestingly, any program I installed remembered old settings from before, so it seems only the list of programs was lost.

For now, the system is fully working again thanks to aptitude, but I am worried about when I eventually move to 18.04.

Anybody have any ideas or suggestions on what I could or should have done differently and do in the future to hopefully prevent this?

Comment: If this a reported ("known") bug, then what is the Launchpad bug number?

Comment: Please tell us the bug ID.   How long did you wait?  I had one 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade take >6 hours, which yes felt like it was stuck; but it was slow because of lack of available disk space as I recall.

Comment: On the other post it links to 946663 as well as others. I wish I could wait, but for several hours it gave no updates at all on that screen other than the CRON message. I don't think disk space is an issue, I should have over 400 GB free. I did get a few more. I am back into the machine, but I lost all programs. I think restoring the home folder should fix it, but those instructions don't work.

Comment: New install only reinstalls default packages. As part of your backup you should be exporting list of installed apps as well as all of /home. But all your settings for every application are in /home and most would not be overwritten, if you do not reformat. Only those with default setting may overwrite, but often ask if you want to keep current or install maintainer's version.