# Ubuntu 22.04 Installation Seemingly Hangs

Tags: system-installation, 22.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my Lenovo laptop (specs below) with a USB. I turned off all internet connection. I chose to install onto an ext4 partition with mount point / and formatting enabled. As per [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613660/stuck-on-removing-conflicting-operating-system-files-while-upgrading-from-14-0) I left my old home directory intact and did not involve it in the installation process in any way. Unfortunately the installation always seemed to get stuck forever on "Detecting file systems..."  `top` reveals that no process is taking more than 5% of CPU, and often less than 1%.

I repeated the exact same steps above (even using the same physical USB and USB port) with Ubuntu 20.04.4. The installation succeeded in under 20 minutes, as it always did for Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04.

Also, with Ubuntu 20.04.4, even if I enabled internet and specified my old home directory as the separate /home mount point, the installation also succeeded in under 20 minutes.

Please tell me how I may install Ubuntu 22.04 in the same or similar way I did for Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you.

Hardware model: Lenovo Ideapad Flex 15

RAM: 8G

Processor: i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80 GHz x 4

Graphics: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)

Disk: 250.1 GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGRy_v7dh6Y) fixed my issue.

In my BIOS I chose legacy boost.  Here're what worked for me.

Make sure you have 1M bios partition (ef02) followed by 100M of EFI (ef00) at the front of your logical disk.  If you use GPT, you can use `gdisk` to create them if you don't.

`sudo mkdir /test; sudo mount -t vfat /dev/your_100M_EFI_partition /test` and observe that this command failed or gave some sort of error message.

`sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/your_100M_EFI_partition; sudo mount -t vfat /dev/your_100M_EFI_partition /test` and check that this time it worked.

Now proceed installing Ubuntu manually (without formatting /home). It should succeed in a reasonable amount of time. Mine was < 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question trying to do a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04.2 from a USB drive on an older Acer Aspire S 13. During shutdown after install finished I would get a few lines in terminal ending with a "BufferIO error on dev sdb3" error.

I was able to solve this by going into the UEFI BIOS and setting it back to Legacy BIOS mode.

I didn't try adding a password for safe boot (one of the questions in setup), so this might have worked, but the system booted fine into Ubuntu after the install on Legacy BIOS.